# TensorFlow assign concat-result tensor to tensor of different shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm using concat to append a tensor t2 of shape [150, 1] onto a tensor t1 which has shape initially of [150, 0]. I want to create a tensor which has shape [150, 1] (concatenate over axis=1), and override t1 with the new tensor. Here is my code:

```
t1.assign(tf.concat(1, [t1, t2]))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 0 and 1
```

Oddly enough, I'm getting the same error when I set axis=0. No idea what's going on; this should be a very easy thing to do. I suspect it has something to do with t1 having a Dimension 1 of 0. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

Turns out, the problem is with "assign", as I'm setting t1 (shape (150, 0)) to the concat result (shape (150, 1)), which is making TF scream at me (rightfully so). Any way around this?

To provide more context, t1 is a tensor which I'm using to store the logit t2 generated from the unrolling of a seq2seq RNN, in which the output sequence has an unknown length. So the size of t1 will be growing in Dimension 1 with every unrolling.

Comment: It sounds like you are on the right track. Can you give a small, self-contained example that shows the problem?

Comment: @PeterHawkins As it turns out, the problem as with "assign", not "concat"; I cannot assign a tensor with shape (150, 1) (the concat-ted tensors) to a tensor which is (150, 0) (t1). Is there a way around this?
Also, not sure if this is odd, but I saw you are (or were) a PhD candidate at Stanford. I'm a freshman undergrad at Stanford!

Answer (score 0):

Use `reshape`:

```
 t1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[150,1])  
 t2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[150])      
 tf.concat(1,[t1,tf.reshape(t2,[150,1])])
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor 'concat_2:0' shape=(150, 2) dtype=float32>
```

Comment: Let me provide some more context. t1 is a tensor which I'm using to store logits and t2 is a logit for an input vector. I'm appending many t2 tensors onto t1, so I cannot reshape t1 every iteration, as it should continue to grow larger. Also, I want the output shape on the first iteration to be (150, 1).

Comment: help me with a small example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related with the shape update on [tf.assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign). You can set `validate_shape` to `False`. This will remove the error on [tf.assign](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign), but will generate a bad behavior because of the shape will not be updated.

It's a TensorFlow's bug and there is a GitHub's issue related with it waiting for R's implementation here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5492